# Subir múltiples fotos symfony2

Tags: symfony2, controller

He seguido el siguiente tutorial https://symfonytricksandcheats.wordpress.com/2015/11/05/subir-multiples-ficheros-a-la-vez/

Y tras seguirlo me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler::handleException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/miweb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php:436
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Error))
#1 {main}
thrown
```

No termino de entenderlo, lo que sé he visto es que el error está en el controlador, el cual es:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $album = new Album();
        $form = $this->createForm(new AlbumType(), $album);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            // Handle the uploaded images
            $files = $form->getData()->getPicture();
// If there are images uploaded
            if($files != null)
            {
                $constraints = array('maxSize'=>'10M', 'mimeTypes' => array('image/*'));
                $uploadFiles = $this->get('app.fileuploader')->create($files, $constraints);

                if($uploadFiles->upload())
                {
                    $album->setPicture($uploadFiles->getFilePaths());
                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                    $em->persist($album);
                    $em->flush();

                    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Las imagenes se han subido con éxito.');

                }
                // If there are file constraint validation issues
                else
                {
                    // Check for errors
                    foreach($uploadFiles->getErrors() as $error)
                    {
                        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', $error);
                    }

                    return $this->render('FrontEndBundle:AlbumOld:uploadAlbum.html.twig', array(
                        'entity' => $album,
                        'form'   => $form->createView(),
                    ));
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('FrontEndBundle:AlbumOld:uploadAlbum.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
```

**Twig**

```
            
                {{ form_label(form.name) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
            
            
                {{ form_label(form.picture) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.picture, { 'full_name': 'simplex_album[picture]' ~ '[]' } ) }}
            

            {% if error is defined %}
                
                    {% for errorMessage in error %}
                        {{ errorMessage }}
                    {% endfor %}
                
            {% endif %} 
            {{ form_rest(form) }}
```

**Album.php**

```
add('name')
            ->add('ìcture', 'file', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'accept' => 'image/*',
                    'multiple' => 'multiple'
                    ),
                'data_class' => null
                )
            );
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'simplex\Entity\Album'
            ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'simplex_album';
    }
}
```

Si elimino el código que está en negrita no me da este error, me da otro diferente, pero es el único código que si lo quito cambia el error que me muestra.

Answer (score 3):

Necesitaria ver el codigo completo del controlador, el FormType, los servicios y la configuracion de estos. De todas formas comprueba:

- que tu controlador extiende la clase base \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
- que tu FormType extiende Symfony\Component\Form\AbstracType
- y si tienes habilitados los formulatios en el fichero de configuracion (config.yml si usas yaml) also asi como

`framework:
      ...
    form: true
      ...`

Que version de Symfony usas?

Comment: La mitad del contenido de esta pregunta son comentarios dirigidos al autor de la pregunta... Quizás deberías separarlos de tu respuesta e incluirlos como comentarios referidos a la pregunta del usuario.

Comment: No tengo suficientes puntos de reputatcion en esta comunidad todavia para enviar directamente comentarios a la pregunta, solo aqui

Comment: No lo sabía. Entonces mejor dejarlo así jejeje